# Obtener id de elementos ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un ListView donde tengo los botones de un View de mi aplicación. El problema es que no se como puedo darles "vida" hallando su identificador. Mi pregunta es:¿Como puedo obtener el id de cada uno de los botones que conforman la lista?

Adjunto código:

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final String[] TITULOS_BTN =
        new String[] { "IBEX 35", "AENA", "BANCO SABADELL", "BANCO  SANTANDER",
                "CAIXABANK", "GAS NATURAL", "FERROVIAL", "IBERDROLA", "TELEFONICA",
                "AMAZON", "MICROSOFT CORPORATION", "APPLE", "NASDAQ", "ORO", "PETROLEO"};

public ListView lvListaDeBotones;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvListaDeBotones = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvListaDeBotones);
        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, TITULOS_BTN);
        lvListaDeBotones.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        lvListaDeBotones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Aquí puedes capturar en on Click de la vista que se crea en general.
            }
        });

        Button btnIbex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noticiasButton);

        btnIbex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), IbexActivity.class );
                startActivity(intent);
                }
         });
}
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_items, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
    Button btnAction = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
    btnAction.setText(values[position]);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

¿Como quedaría el código para poder hallar sus id?

Comment: ¿A qué te referieres con ID? ¿A el nombre?

Comment: quiero hacer un OnClickListener a cada uno de lo botones para poder encadenar una activity. Yo referencio al boton con id que le pongo en el xml. Pero al hacerlo distinto de esta forma no se como debo rferencias cada boton para poder darle "vida"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno como te comentaba, para esto debes utilizar `holders` y `tags` para tu vista, aunque para tu caso no es tan necesario porque solo vas a cargar botones. Sustituye tu clase `MyAdapter` por esta:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements View.OnClickListener{
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;
        private int position;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.listview_items, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            View rowView = convertView;

            if (rowView == null || !( rowView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder)) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.btnAction = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
                holder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(this);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            holder.btnAction.setText(values[position]);
            holder.btnAction.setTag(position);
            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (int) v.getTag();
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 13:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 14:
                    Toast.makeText(context, values[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            private Button btnAction;
        }
    }
```

Ó si te quieres ahorrar los Switch cases, implementa [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) para tu botón, aunque es más código y hace el mismo trabajo. Saludos.

Comment: bien he realizado las modificaciones en el código pero no puedo compliarlo en el ordenador que me encuentro asi que luego te ajuntare el resultado @Andrespengineer. Tuve que adjuntar una libreria para el parametro NonNull lo único que me aparecian dos librerias escogi la que el studio me daba como predeterminada hice bien ?import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

Comment: Si, esa es la librería, es para evitar el warning que me lanzaba.

Comment: Picando código he creado los intent en cada case del switch pero a la hora de llamar al método **starActivity(intent)**. Me da un error de que "Can´t not resolv method". He añadido la actividad al manifest y no se que hacer?? alguna idea?? @Andrespengineer

Comment: Claro, crea una variable public Activity activity; y pasa el Activity en el constructor MyAdapter y haz this.activity = activity; llama activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Lo que pasa es que startActivity no existe en una clase que extiende de adapter.

Comment: y en el mainactivity que es donde hago la llamada **MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, TITULOS_BTN);** Debo sobrecargar el metodo con un parametro mas que seria la activity. He puesto a null y me da fallo que deberia de poner?

Comment: Deja todo como esta en mainactivity. En el adapter crea una variable private Activity activity; y en el constructor de MyAdapter haz esto: this.activity = (Activity)context; y despues para llamar a la actividad con el intent activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: gracias figura ;D

Answer (score 1):

No esta muy claro lo que quieres , no entendí todo lo que pusiste, asi que me basare en esto : ¿Como puedo obtener el id de cada uno de los botones que conforman la lista?

No puedes utilizar un id como variable, pero puedes declarar todo en forma de lista con sus respectivos id y utilizar el indice de cada objeto de la lista para llamarlos. Asi mira:

```
Button [] btns =new CustomFontTextView[16];

btns[0] = (Button) findviewById(R.id.miBoton1);
btns[1] = (Button) findviewById(R.id.miBoton2);
btns[2] = (Button) findviewById(R.id.miBoton3);
btns[3] = (Button) findviewById(R.id.miBoton4);
btns[4] = (Button) findviewById(R.id.miBoton5);
```

etc...

Y asi podrias trabajar con ellos llamandolos por su numero como se te antoje, desde un bucle hasta creo hacerle como tu quieres, ¿Quieres que segun un texto se ponga en cierto boton? Pues despues pasaria todo a un Map

```
Map<String, Integer> botonesPorNombre = new HashMap<>();

botonesPorNombre.put("IBEX 35",0);
botonesPorNombre.put("AENA",1);
```

etc... bla bla bla

y ya al llamar al boton seria

```
btns[botonesPorNombre.get("IBEX 35");
```

O

```
btns[botonesPorNombre.get("AENA");
```

etc...

Ya donde lo vayas aplicar queda en ti , pero asi podrias trabajar con lindos botones con nombre.

```
    public void botonsito(String nombreBotonsito,String textoCool){
    btns[botonesPorNombre.get(nombreBotonsito)].setText(textoCool);
    }
```

etc etc etc

Es lo mejor que puedo explicarte desde el celular mientras camino, suerte ;D

Comment: El se refiere a que solo tiene un ID de botón, pero para cada botón que carga con un solo ID, quiere asignar diferentes acciones. Es decir, en su ejemplo tiene 15 Botones, que se recrean con un solo ID que es btnAction, ahora bien, para cada uno de esos botones debe definir una acción distinta. Tu solución es buena y se puede aplicar para el caso de los Holders, sin embargo ahí le estás trabajando con varios IDs cuando solo tiene uno. No le quito mérito a tu respuesta, funcionaría para ese caso +1.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Oh , ya entiendo, si de hecho es el que utilizo en mis adapters para hacer aparecer y desaparecer cosas, gracias n_n

Comment: gracias por la colaboracion @Eduardo Ricardez se agradece

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de casos con objetos dinamicos lo mejor que podes hacer es usar "tags" al usar ids tenes unas leves chances de que ese id ya este asignado en el paquete de android y te cause problemas. te dejo un ejemplo de como lo haría. dentro de tu metodo `getView()` al definir tu boton le agregas el tag dependiendo del position. `btnAction.setTag(position);` despues para acceder a los botones.

```
Button btnAction = (Button) padre.findViewWithTag()//el position que desees.
```